# How to restrict time options exact hour value, should be restrict after the time passed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need time options only `11 AM to 1 PM (1:00:00 PM only)` and If system time is `1:00:01 PM` also should not be allowed. if time passed after `1 PM` I need to get the option availability as false.As of now till `1:59:59 PM` I'm getting value as true. If my system time moved to `2 PM` only  getting false.
Suggest me how to get the solution for this. I should allow only `1:00:00 PM` and should not be allowed any other options.

```
public timeOptions = ['11 AM', '12 PM', '1 PM'];
  private currentTime: string[] = new Date()
    .toLocaleTimeString('en-US')
    .split(' ');
  private formattedTime: string = `${this.currentTime[0].split(':')[0]} ${
    this.currentTime[1]
  }`;
  private timeIndexOnOptions: number = this.timeOptions.indexOf(
    this.formattedTime
  );


  public timeOptionAvaialable(): void {
    let isOptionAvailable = this.timeIndexOnOptions != -1 ? true : false;
    console.log(isOptionAvailable);
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-image-video-preview-final-s74tep?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.component.css)

Answer (score 1):

here is some piece of code

```js
const timeOptions = ['11 AM', '12 PM', '1 PM'];
const today = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US').split(' ')
const timeSplit = today[0].split(':')
const index = timeOptions.indexOf(timeSplit[0] + ' ' + today[1])
// it will not wait for 1:00:00 it return false when 12:59:59 hit
if (index > -1 && index !== (timeOptions.length - 1)) {
  console.log(true);
} else {
  console.log(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It look like you want to decide if `currentTime` is in an interval. May I then suggest an alternate approach? Create a date object that represents the beginning of the interval and a date object that represents the end of the interval and check whether current time is in that interval.

```
const startHours = 11;
const endHours = 13;

// create a Date object for 11 AM today
const startTime = new Date();
startTime.setHours(startHours, 0, 0, 0);

// create a Date object for 1 PM today
const endTime = new Date();
endTime.setHours(endHours, 0, 0, 0);

// check if current time is in the interval
const currentTime = new Date();
const isOptionAvailable = currentTime > startTime && currentTime < endTime
```